# Angular 2 way data binding is lost after loading bound content from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, data-binding

I have a `</p>` element that can be edited through an `</input>` element with angularjs. After I reload the `<p>` element from html 5 localStorage on page refresh with the content entered previously I lose the 2 way data binding between the `<p>` and the `<input>` element. What is happening,

Can you explain to me in such case how angular mechanism works? using angular's ngStorage did not solve the issue. Do I need a router? If yes what is a router in angular how can it solve my issue, can you link me?

Comment: Can you show your code?